# Get the relative path in swift

Tags: swift, relative-path

I have a swift file on my server that I access using an absolute path.
Eventually, the path will change when I'll host the server somewhere.

---

#### The current path:

```
 "/Users/user/projects/ios-projects/project-name/resources/myfolder/myfile"
```

#### What I want to achieve:

```
"../../../resources/myfolder/myfile"
```

I've looked into relative paths in swift, but everything looks outdated and suggests using 3rd party libraries.

Also some suggested using `FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath` but it is giving me a different path.

##### FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath

```
"/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname-ebbjtdinidfrryclqgpbyitmljjo/Build/Products/Debug"
```

Is there a way to get the desired relative path using `FileManager`?

Answer (score 0):

`/Users/user` points to the home directory of user `user`.

You get the URL of the home folder of the current user with

```
let homeDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())
```

But this doesn't work in a sandboxed environment.